# Why time does not show when I pass a List(of Date) as datasource for a Repeater

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, datetime

English is not my first language.

I want to bind a **List(of Date)** to a **Repeater control**. I take any one day and I fill a list with the 24 hours of the day. Then, when I pass that list as a **Datasource** for the **Repeater**, I expect to see: *'12/10/2021 12:00:00 am', '12/10/2021 01:00:00 am', '12/10/2021 02:00 am', '12/10/2021 03:00:00 am'*, etc. But instead the list renders as: *'12/10/2021 12:00:00 am', '12/10/2021 12:00:00 am', '12/10/2021 12:00:00 am', '12/10/2021 12:00:00 am'*, etc.

Why the **Time part** is missing when you pass the **list(of date)** as the **datasource** of the control?

My Code:

```
Dim dDate As Date = Date.Now
Dim oHours As New List(Of Date)
For i As Integer = 0 To 23
    oHours.Add(New Date(dDate.Year, dDate.Month, dDate.Day, i, 0, 0))
Next

With Repeater1
    .Datasource = oHours
    .Databind()
End With
```

Markup:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <div>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Date")%>'>                        
                     <%# Eval("Date")%>                                                  
                 </asp:LinkButton>                      
            </div>
       </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: `Eval("Date")` will echo just the date without time information. You need to format the output or use a function.

Comment: Eval("Date").toString("MM/dd/aaaa hh:mm") does the same, outputs the date part but ignores the time part

Answer (score 0):

Try passing just Now() to your dim statement like this:
Dim dDate As Date = Now()

I think the Date.Now only sees the Date tag.